# How to execute function in event listener only every second time event is happening?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, event-listener

According to [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/) I was trying to detect fullscreen state change. With the following event listener function the code in between is executed every time the fullscreen state changes (when entering fullscreen and when cancelling fullscreen). But I want to execute my code only when fullscreen is cancelled. Is there an easy way to execute my code within that function only every second time (I know it's quick and dirty) or even better: how to detect cancelling fullscreen and execute code afterwards?

Here the code:

```
var fullscreenState = $('#wrapper');
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.fullscreen)? "" : "not ";        
            alert('fullscreen');
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.mozFullScreen)? "" : "not ";
        alert('fullscreen');

}, false);

document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.webkitIsFullScreen)? "" : "not ";       
        alert('fullscreen');

}, false);
```

Comment: Is that a jQuery object you're using with innerHTML ?

Comment: Now realised that I dont need the jQuery Object. I deleted the selected object ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean that keeps track of your state (fullscreen is false when you're not in fullscreen).

```
var fullscreen;
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
  if (fullscreen = !fullscreen) return;
  /* code here is executed only when fullscreen is canceled */

  fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.fullscreen)? "" : "not ";        
            alert('fullscreen');
}, false);
```

MDN Also provides some information on how to check the fullscreen state without relying on quick and dirty hacks:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/fullscreenchange

```
if ( document.fullscreenEnabled ) {
  // code here
}
```

Not sure about the browser compatibility for it though.

Comment: Thx so much! I'm still a noob and I don't know what exactly happens in this function but it finally works. Thx so much :D

Comment: The initial value of fullscreen is false (undefined actually, but equivalent in this case). Each time you enter the callback, the value is changed from false to true or from true to false. If the new value is true (when fullscreen has just been activated), the function exits on the first line, preventing the rest of the code to be executed.

Comment: yeah, thx! After deleting the unnecessary and confusing code (    var fullscreenState = $('#wrapper'); and     fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.webkitIsFullScreen)? "" : "not ";) it makes sense to me. :)

Comment: This seems pretty simple and genius! Upvote for that. Even if I do not quite understand why the boolean changes on each event. I only see a check IF it is not equal but where is the increment or change or whatever. I am a noob, too, it seems. And now my additional question: How is the way to make this go the other way around? This: if (!(forth = !forth)) return; ?

Comment: @Garavani The variable is changed inside the if clause - notice the assignment. In JS assignments evaluate to the new value. `fullscreen` starts as falsy (undefined) and becomes true the first time the handler is executed, then it becomes false and the handler returns early, then it becomes true again and it executes entirely, etc. To reverse it, you can simply initialize fullscreen to a truthy value (`true`). Perhaps you would also want to rename it to something more appropriate for your use case like "notFullscreen" or "windowMode".